# Create Fail2ban Rule for Named

Tags: regex, bind, fail2ban

As I am trying to create a rule for Fail2ban which seems to me missing for a long while as I being really nerved by in the past I'm also willing to submit it to the world :-)

What's been done?

1. Already created a file under fail2ban/filter/named-antispam.conf
2. Created it with content

```
    #cat filter.d/named-antispam.conf
    [Definition]
    prefregex = ([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])\s([0-9]|[0-9][0-9])\s([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])
    failregex = ^rate limit drop all response to <HOST>$
```

and jail.conf

```
#Disabled for Writing this Articel
[named-antispam]
enabled = false
filter = named-antispam
logpath  = /var/log/named/rate.log
bantime      = 2628000
maxretry     = 30
findtime     = 60
```

3. checked what happen to fail2ban if I enable it and set to it debug?

```
2021-01-26 11:25:19,461 fail2ban.filterpyinotify[14180]: DEBUG   Event queue size: 16
2021-01-26 11:25:19,462 fail2ban.filterpyinotify[14180]: DEBUG   <_RawEvent cookie=0 mask=0x2 name='' wd=2 >
```

If I disable the rule I can set debug without that error - so it seems to me that I have some kind of error which I can't figure out and that's why I ask here. and at the Ending - yes i have a lot of entrys in my log but fail2ban does not care off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide what is the issue basically, moreover neither a log excerpt with messages you want to catch in filter, nor the atempt what `fail2ban-regex -v` find with filter.

I guess the message looks like:

```
Jan 26 14:00:10 srv named[26403]: client 192.0.2.100#21324 (example.com): rate limit drop all response to 192.0.2.0/24
```

Then here are 2 things to note - firstly the IP is after client (here `192.0.2.100`), and at end it has a subnet (IP/CIDR notation, here `192.0.2.0/24`).

If you want to ban a subnet (if your fail2ban and choosen banaction are able to ban subnets at all), you can use depending on your version:

either this (if your fail2ban supports `<SUBNET>`):

```
failregex = ^\s*\S+\s+named(?:\[\d+\])?: [^:]+: rate limit drop all response to <SUBNET>
```

or this:

```
failregex = ^\s*\S+\s+named(?:\[\d+\])?: [^:]+: rate limit drop all response to (?:<F-IP4>\d+\.\S+</F-IP4>|<F-IP6>\w+\:\S+</F-IP6>)
```

You can also ban IP instead of subnet, then use either this one:

```
failregex = ^\s*\S+\s+named(?:\[\d+\])?: client <ADDR>[^:]*: rate limit drop all response
```

You can also check it with `fail2ban-regex`, for example:

```bsh
msg='Jan 26 14:00:10 srv named[26403]: client 192.0.2.100#21324 (example.com): rate limit drop all response to 192.0.2.0/24'
fail2ban-regex "$msg" '^\s*\S+\s+named(?:\[\d+\])?: [^:]+: rate limit drop all response to <SUBNET>'
...
Lines: 1 lines, 0 ignored, 1 matched, 0 missed
```

or to test the filter with a log-file use this:

```bsh
fail2ban-regex /var/log/named/rate.log named-antispam
```

---

As for your `prefregex` and `failregex` - they are just not correct. Neither prefregex nor failregex must contain a part with timestamp matching `datepattern` (read a how-to's in our [wiki](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/How-fail2ban-works) or [manual](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/fail2ban/jail.conf.5.en.html), it contains:
*NOTE: the `failregex` will be applied to the remaining part of message after `prefregex` processing (if specified), which in turn takes place after `datepattern` processing (whereby the string of timestamp matching the best pattern, cut out from the message).*

Also `prefregex` makes sense, if you need some prefiltering, for instance you have more than one failregex (and such a regex's will be applied either on whole part of line, or on part matched RE enclosed between `<F-CONTENT>` and `</F-CONTENT>`, if it is specified.
If no prefiltering expected, `prefregex` makes few sense.

Anyway if you need it for some reason, it would look like this:

```
prefregex = ^\s*\S+\s+named(?:\[\d+\])?: <F-CONTENT>.+</F-CONTENT>$ 

failregex = ^[^:]+: rate limit drop all response to <SUBNET>
#failregex = ^[^:]+: rate limit drop all response to (?:<F-IP4>\d+\.\S+</F-IP4>|<F-IP6>\w+\:\S+</F-IP6>)
#failregex = ^client <ADDR>[^:]*: rate limit drop all response
```